# Monitoring ASA packet loss via SNMP

Tags: monitoring, cisco-asa, snmp

I want to monitor packet loss on my ASA 5505 VPN endpoints using SNMP.  This is so I can graph the rates in Cacti and/or get alerts in Nagios.

However, I am not sure what SNMP values I should use to measure packet loss.

In the ASA I can run `sh interface Internet stats` to show traffic statistics for the interface connected to the Internet.  This shows 1 minute and 5 minute drop rates.

- Are these measures an indicator of packet loss?
- Are there SNMP values I can access that correspond to those values?
- Should I be looking at different values?
- Is the ASA even able to measure packet loss?

Comment: Should you be experiencing packet loss on a firewall interface in the first place?

Comment: I have links I know are often lossy, and I know that an ASA at a site where the VPN tunnel was not performing well showed drop rates for `sh interface Internet`.  I want to better understand which sites have lossy links at problem levels so I can do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

Google for "cacti cisco ASA template". That will tell you which OIDs you need.

Mind you that the SNMP indexes for VPN interfaces *don't exist* unless the tunnel is up!

Comment: Thanks - the ASA templates I have for Cacti don't actually gather this, but the standard Interface templates gather Errors/Discards.  But since ewwhite's comment above I am wondering whether I am barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Well, watching for them would be good regardless, but yes, if **VPN** packets are being dropped, you have bigger problems.

Comment: If packets are lost en route, does the ASA know?  I know packets are discarded when the buffer fills up, but what about errors?  Is that related to packet loss?

Comment: An IPsec VPN is simply a method of sending encrypted IP-in-IP packets. Both the outer layer (normal IP) and inner (encrypted) packets can contain transmission errors. HOWEVER, since the encapsulated, encrypted packets are both error-checked internally AND have to match for decryption to work, as well as being verified on the outer, plain IP layer... if there are errors in those, something is very, very wonky. For one, the odds of getting a bad VPN packet to CRC on the outer layer are near-zero to begin with. The odds of a correct VPN packet not checking out in plain IP **are** zero.

Answer (score 1):

Object  cufwAspFlowDropsTable
OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.491.1.5.3.4
Description This table lists all the ASP flow drops on this firewall device.
https://snmp.cloudapps.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.491.1.5.3.4#oidContent

CLI equivalent: show asp drop

Comment: Surprised to see this revived 9 years later.  I don't work with ASA any more but I hope this helps someone :-)